# How to archive weak links with NSKeyedArchiver?

Tags: ios, parent, composite, weak-references, nskeyedarchiver

I have a composite structure with many properties in the components.
I've implemented NSCoding protocol for every participant, the strong properties get archived well.

But every component have a weak link to its parent. I think if I simply encode the parents as the rest owned object, then redundant/duplicated instances gonna born upon decoding.

How to archive such a relationships in an object graph?

Comment: Handled automatically? What now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I simply have to use conditional encoding - http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Archiving/Articles/archives.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000946-142208-BBCFHBHA - on weak references. I'll try it out soon.

> Typically, conditional objects are used to encode weak, or
>   non-retained, references to objects.

Answer (score -1):

According http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/codingctypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001294-BBCBDHBI

> You can’t encode a pointer and get back something useful at decode time. You have to encode the information to which the pointer is pointing. This is true in non-keyed coding as well.